# Sed - How to read a file line by line and go the path mentioned in the file then replace string?

Tags: regex, sed

I am on a new project where I need to add some strings to all the API names, which are exported
Someone hinted this can be done with simple sed commands.

What really needed is : Example :

In my project say 100 files and many files have something like the below pattern

- in file1 its mentioned at some line :   export(xyx);
- in file2 its mentioned at some line : export (abc);

What is needed here is to replace the
**xyz with xyz_temp** and
**abc with abc_temp.**

Now the problem is these APIs are in different folders and different files.

Fortunately, I got to know we can redirect the result of **cscope** tool to some file with matching patterns.
so I did redirect the result of a search of the "export" string and I got below. Say file I have exported the scope result - export_api.txt as below.

1. **/path1/file1.txt   export(xyz);**
2. **/path2/file2.txt   export(abc);**

Now, I am not sure how to use sed to do this automation of

1. Reading this export_ap.txt
2. Reading each line
3. Replacing the string as above.

Any direction would highly appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of files which need to be changed and your replacement only needs to append `_tmp`, then this can be accomplished with a single sed call:

```
sed -i 's/export(\(abc\|xyz\));/export(\1_tmp);/' files...
```

`-i` will modify the files in-place, overwriting them.

If you don't care for what you are going to replace, but append a postfix to *all* export expressions, match any identifier. Here is one such example:

```
export(\([^)]*\))
```

Depending on your expressions and valid identifier names, you might want to or need to change this to one of:

- `export(\(.*\))`
- `export(\([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\))`
- `export(\([_a-zA-Z"'][_a-zA-Z0-9"']*\))`
- `export(\([_a-zA-Z]*\))`
- …

Another option would be to only match lines containing "export(" and then replace the closing parenthisis (given that your input lines contain the token ");" only once):

```
sed -i '/export(/s/);/_tmp);/' files...
# or reusing the complete match:
sed -i '/export(/s/);/_tmp&/' files...
```

This avoids the backreference and makes the regular expression simpler, because they can now be of fixed size

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I really can't add abc\|xyz in the first export, sed should read whatever there. any suggestions ? 

something line read every file path , go to that file, and change anything with export(somestring) to exprt(somestring_temp)

Comment: @pradiptart sed uses standard regular expressions, you can put whatever you need there. I've extended my answer with a few examples, which might or might not work for your specific case(s).

Comment: Will check and update you!! Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I have just tried below and its throwing error :
sed -i 's/export(.*);/export(\1_tmp);/' x.c but getting Error : 
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @pradiptart you need to capture the contents in a group. I've updated my answer

Comment: This is working at last. :) !! Thanks.

while read -r path snippet; do
     sed -i 's/export(\([^)]*\));/export(\1_tmp2);/' "$path" ;
done < exp.txt

Comment: @pradiptart glad I could help! I added another option which simplifies the regex even further. Maybe it can be useful to you in the future too

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `read` builtin to parse the line in your `export_api.txt` file, then call sed on each file. Pattern match the `export` snippet to choose the correct sed invocation. The way `read` is invoked here assumes that your path and snippet are delimited by IFS and that path does not contain any whitespace or separators:

```
while read -r path snippet; do
  case "$snippet" in
    *abc*) sed -i 's/export(abc);/export(abc_tmp);/' "$path" ;;
    *xyz*) sed -i 's/export(xyz);/export(xyz_tmp);/' "$path" ;;
  esac
done < export_api.txt
```

**NOTE:** this will change/overwrite any of your files. Your files might be left in a broken state.

PS I wonder why you cannot use your IDE to search/replace those occurrences?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, Search and replace will be time-consuming as there would be thousand with these export() and moreover, I can't search with the API as the API names are different. So I could only search using the "export" and add a string to whatever available there, I can't change it as well. 

That is , I need to add some string to the API names inside the export() for all those occurrences throughout the project. So I will replace the above in the while loop hope that will help.

Comment: One doubt here is, we really do not know the API name inside the Files right ? 
we need to feed the file alone to Sed and sed have to check anything on export to replace the same with adding some string at the end. 
I don't find the above will help as you are searching the abc and xyz , which in real case we do not know in advance. ? Any suggestions.

Comment: @pradiptart I don't understand. You want to replace something, so you have to know what to replace, don't you? The example file given by you has a file name and the thing to replace, so as I understood it, the file already contains the text to replace. By pattern matching, you select the appropriate sed invocation.

Comment: Yes, the file has the lines with path and the export() , Issue is its 1000 in number and 
It won't be possible to append the API name before the commands you shared for every line right ?

To make it simple, sed command just has to add some string at every API name. yeah to search we can use "export" in that line after which the string has to be replaced till ) bracket closing.

Comment: @pradiptart I still don't understand the concern, sorry. Calling sed on 1000 files shouldn't be a problem and usually takes less than a few seconds (depending on file size of course). If you only need to append a suffix to _all_ API exports, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289280/112968). Maybe you can make it clearer by providing one example and one counter example in your question? In which cases wouldn't this answer work?

Comment: Really sorry !!!
Actually, what I mean is in your answer you have mentioned abc or xyz explicitly right ? You want them to be added by me is that correct ? 
I may not able to add those in real as it would be 1000 different API names,  what I really need is sed will simply reach the export () and add a string say " temp" to every API name. something line read every file path , go to that file, and change anything with export(somestring) to exprt(somestring_temp)

Comment: @pradiptart I think I understand now. If all you want to do is change "export(x)" to "export(x_y)" for every occurrence of "export(…)" (potentially limited to certain files), see [my second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289280/112968)